# Can't delete Google Directory schema?

Tags: amazon-iam, google-apis-explorer

As part of my experimenting with G Suite SSO/SAML w/ AWS IAM, I created a schema using the Directory API explorer.

When I try to delete the schema, I get the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Input: 4gI5BqVmTDOZNQsZDjClbw=="
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Input: 4gI5BqVmTDOZNQsZDjClbw=="
 }
}
```

After initially creating the schema, I added a value to the one field within it to my user.

I have created and immediately deleted another schema (without populating the field for my user), which deleted successfully.

The 'invalid input' ID above is the ID of the only field in the schema I am trying to delete.

Comment: have you tried removing the schema from the user it was attached to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In speaking to G Suite support, this cannot yet be done; this is a known bug relating to custom schemas used by SAML applications.